# python isabs does not recognize Windows UNC path as absolute path

Tags: python, path

Running on Python 2.7.10 on windows.

```
> os.path.isabs(r"\\\unc_path\file")
False

> os.path.isabs(r"\\\unc_path\")
False
```

Is this by design?

Comment: Please provide the literal path name you are testing. The paths you have listed aren't UNC paths since they don't being with a double-backslash.

Comment: Wouldn't you need a device to make that absolute? `os.path.isabs(r"c:\unc_path\file")` or os.path.isabs(r"\\unc_path\file")

Comment: Also, see the note [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#module-os.path): "*Note On Windows, many of these functions do not properly support UNC pathnames.*"

Comment: FYI, `os.path.isabs(r"\unc_path\file")` returns `True` for me, not `False`. On the other hand, `os.path.isabs(r"\unc_path\")` returns `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Formatted your code as code. Emphasize what is input (prompt style) land what is output. But you do have a **syntax error**. Use your real code, without typos, please!

Answer (score 1):

`os.path.isabs` will only return `True` for a UNC path if there is some path information (even just a single slash) after the `\\server\share` part.

```
Python 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:24:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.path.isabs('\\\\server\\share')
False
>>> os.path.isabs('\\\\server\\share\\')
True
```

To understand why, it is helpful to understand that `isabs` is just a tiny bit of code on top of `splitdrive`. In `ntpath`, the Windows implementation of `os.path`, it looks like this:

```
def isabs(s):
    """Test whether a path is absolute"""
    s = splitdrive(s)[1]
    return s != '' and s[:1] in '/\\'
```

The `splitdrive` implementation is intended to handle both paths with drive letters as well as UNC paths, and to have some consistency between them. Documentation for `ntpath.splitdrive` says:

> If the path contained a drive letter, drive_or_unc will contain
>   everything up to and including the colon. e.g. splitdrive("c:/dir")
>   returns ("c:", "/dir")
>
> If the path contained a UNC path, the drive_or_unc will contain the
>   host name and share up to but not including the fourth directory
>   separator character. e.g. splitdrive("//host/computer/dir") returns
>   ("//host/computer", "/dir")

So...

```
>>> os.path.splitdrive('\\\\server\\share')
('\\\\server\\share', '')
```

You can see that `isabs` will return `False`.

That being said, this behavior changed between Python 2.7.7 and Python 2.7.8:

```
Python 2.7.7 (default, Oct 12 2015, 14:42:48) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.path.isabs('\\\\server\\share')
True
>>> os.path.isabs('\\\\server\\share\\')
True
```

The change was to fix a [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue21672) in `os.path.join`. I'm not totally sure if the Python developers realized it would be a breaking change for some `os.path` functions, but the behavior is consistent with Python 3.5:

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.path.isabs('\\\\server\\share')
False
>>> os.path.isabs('\\\\server\\share\\')
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pay attention to string escaping, which is usually done with `\`.

For example `\n` is the newline symbol. `\\` yields the **single** slash `\`.

Thus, the string `"\\something"` will print as `\something`.

If you wanted to have the *contents* `\\something` you need to type `\\\\something`, i.e. double any backslash. Alternatively you can use **raw strings**: `r"\\something"` will also work. You cannot enter a newline there anymore, but you don't have them in path names anyway.

So the path names you typed may not be what you think they are. `\` is a special character, and unfortunately Microsoft back in the time of DOS thought it would be a good character to use as path separator. Unix operating systems (where most programming languages, and the convention of using the `\` [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) originate) use the forward slash `/`, which is unproblematic.